# Full text search failing on words with no stop lists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I am working on MsSQL 2008  server, I disabled all the stoplists that exist
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_stopwords does not returna nything
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_stoplists does not return anything either

SELECT DISTINCT u.ID, Name FROM University u 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(University, (Name), '"University" AND "of" AND "Phoenix"') AS uni_tbl1 ON uni_tbl1.[KEY] = u.ID

this search fails because of the word "of". If I take that word out of the search string the results return just fine.

Please help! all suggestions are appreciated.

Regards
Zaid

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to rebuild your full-text index?

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG catalog_name REBUILD
```